# ¿Etiqueta OOP como sinónimo de POO?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Recién aparece la primera pregunta con etiqueta [oop](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop). Siendo muy estrictos, lo correcto es mantener el sitio en español y usar [POO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poo), pero es muy común que la gente encuentre literatura haciendo referencia a OOP.

Como nadie tiene 5 de puntuación en esa etiqueta, ¿se podría poner ese sinónimo de una vez por parte de alguien que posea poder suficiente? :)

Comment: Alfabravo @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' hecho. He añadido oop como sinonimo de poo.

Comment: Gracias, @Pikoh, siempre al quite :)

Comment: Gracias, @Pikoh !!